# Java Check Duplicates in data file and add number

Tags: java

```
I have data file like:

First Name,Last Name,Number
Robert,Thomas
Jimmy,Johns
Robert,Thomas
Conner,Thomas
Robert,Thomas
Jimmy,Johns
```

---

```
Outfile Should be like:

First Name,Last Name,Number
Robert,Thomas,1
Robert,Thomas,2
Robert,Thomas,3
Jimmy,Johns,1
Jimmy,Johns,2
Conner,Thomas,
```

---

I wrote code, but actually it's removing those dupicates data, but I want write number in last fields..

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Data_Prospect_key1 {

    public static void delFileFromDir(String dirPath) {
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if (dir.listFiles() == null)
            return;
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (!file.isDirectory())
                file.delete();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            
            BufferedReader br = null;
            BufferedWriter bfAlldcount = null;

             File folderall = new File("Data_File_IN");
             File[] BFFileall = folderall.listFiles();
             
             for (File file : BFFileall) {
                 
                 String str = file.getName(); 
                 
                 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                 
                 String count = "Data_File_OUT\\" + "OUT_" + str;
                 bfAlldcount = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(count));
                 
                 String line;
                 line = br.readLine();
                 
                 Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 
                 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     
                     String[] actionID = line.split("\\,");
                     
                     String PFN = actionID[0].trim();
                     String PLN = actionID[1].trim();
                     
                    maps.put(PFN, PLN);
                     
                 }
                 
                 for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : maps.entrySet()) {
                     
                        System.out.println("First Name: -" + entry.getKey() + " , Last Name="
                            + entry.getValue());
             
                    }
                 
             }
            
        } catch(Exception lettercount) {
             lettercount.printStackTrace();
         }
        
    }

}
```

---

My code output is just remove duplicate..
output is:

```
Robert,Thomas
Jimmy,Johns 
Robert,Thomas
```

Comment: Why are you mainitaing First Name,Last Name,Number.Simply use MAP and you can achieve the target

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, reading data file skip first line and than find dupicates and add number in last field, Please help me.. Thanks!!

Comment: You are using MAP to store first name and last name so you are facing the pblm .Duplicate key is not allowed in map

Comment: ooh ok, Thank you so much, What i need to use instead of MAP??

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pointers

1. Use a Scanner to read the file, it's much simpler and gives cleaner code
2. When you find a name see if it exists in a HashMap of names. If not add it with a value of 0.
3. Increment the now guaranteed value in the HashMap by one.
4. Print all keys and values from the HashMap

Like this.

```
package se.wederbrand.stackoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingRobert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<>();

        Scanner scanner;
        if (args.length == 0) {
            // for testing
            String input = "First Name,Last Name,Number\n" +
                    "Robert,Thomas\n" +
                    "Jimmy,Johns\n" +
                    "Robert,Thomas\n" +
                    "Conner,Thomas\n" +
                    "Robert,Thomas\n" +
                    "Jimmy,Johns";
            scanner = new Scanner(input);
        }
        else {
            scanner = new Scanner(args[0]);
        }

        // Skip one line with the heading
        scanner.nextLine();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!names.containsKey(line)) {
                names.put(line, 0);
            }

            names.put(line, names.get(line) + 1);
        }

        for (String name : names.keySet()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= names.get(name); i++) {
                System.out.println(name + " " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I tried that thing but its not working correctly, its needs to be in sorting order when change add new number.. please help me.. Thanks in advanced!!!!

Comment: How should it be sorted?

Comment: like, Robert in first 3 lines and than next one.. like that.. I am confused, I am beginners in Java please help me!!

Comment: Should Robert be first because he's first in the input file or because he has the most number of occurances?

Comment: no, I am asking.. Do i need to sort file first by first and last name.. than first name and last name change add number from beginning??

Comment: ohh ok, I thought, I need to sort first than when value get change start number from beginning.. Thank you so much.. Actually, I beginning, I didn't know that.. Thank you once again..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. I trying to write to read from file and do same thing.. thank you so much once again!!

Answer (score 0):

I am having some confusion regarding the approach.
You are having file containing the format :

```
Robert,Thomas
Jimmy,Johns
Robert,Thomas
Conner,Thomas
Robert,Thomas
Jimmy,Johns
```

And you want to get the list of Firstname and LastName(No duplicate).

So what you can do read the file line by line and put the FS,PS in Map and follow the process till EOF.As MAP has the property that no duplicate Key exist so you will get the desired output

```
Robert,Thomas
Jimmy,Johns
Conner,Thomas
```

Comment: my code removing duplicates, instead of removing just add number at last 1 2 3.....Robert,Thomas,1
Robert,Thomas,2
Robert,Thomas,3
Jimmy,Johns,1
Jimmy,Johns,2
Conner,Thomas,

Comment: @user3187463 I accept dear.You need to read the file line by line and put the FS PS in MAP.